# Find Antiderivative: $\int \frac{x^2(6+3\sin(x^2)-2x^2\cos(x^2))}{(2+\sin(x^2))^2} dx$

Tags: integration

I am looking for a way to find
$$\int\!\frac{x^2(6+3\sin(x^2)-2x^2\cos(x^2))}{(2+\sin(x^2))^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \left(=\frac{x^3}{2+\sin(x^2)}+c\right)$$
I know the result as I started with the RHS and because differentiation is easy it is no problem to get $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{x^3}{2+\sin(x^2)}=\frac{x^2(6+3\sin(x^2)-2x^2\cos(x^2))}{(2+\sin(x^2))^2},$$ I just can't find a way to get from the LHS to the result.

Some context for the problem: I am currently writing questions for students in their first semester of university and was looking for some examples to show them exactly this point, that differentiation is easy and everyone can do it with their eyes closed while integration can be extremely hard. I have the usual examples e.g. $\int\! e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ where it es easy to show that an antiderivative must exist, but we don't really know how to get it (at least not using only elementary functions). I was then looking for an example where one can actually get the antiderivative, it is just really difficult.

I have found some examples that fit my needs, so I have enough material for my students, but this is the only one left where I couldn't figure something out; it has become more of a leisure problem for me (which obviously starts to drive me crazy...) Any input is welcome, although I am mainly looking for a solution that utilizes only beginners knowledge, so the standard known antiderivatives of polynomials, exponential/logarithm/trigonometric functions, integration by parts, integration by substitution and using partial fractions.

Comment: Take $t = \dfrac{x^3}{2 + \sin x^2}$.

Comment: Motivation of considering your substitution?

Comment: Write your left hand side as:
$$3\color{blue}{\int \frac{x^2}{\sin(x^2)+2}~dx}-2\int \frac{x^4\cos(x^2)}{(\sin(x^2)+2)^2}$$
And apply integration by parts on the blue coloured term.

Comment: If you're looking for a slightly unusual and not-so-easy example for students, try $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\frac{1}{1+\cos x+\sin x}\,dx}$. If you're looking for a standard example where an antiderivative is not easy to find without guessing, try $\int\sec x\,dx$.

Comment: @Idonknow Because $$\frac{\mathrm d \left(\frac{x^3}{2+\sin(x^2)}\right)}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{x^2(6+3\sin(x^2)-2x^2\cos(x^2))}{(2+\sin(x^2))^2}$$.

Comment: @Hirshy  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

the best way is to recognize that the function to be integrate is in the form:

$$\frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}$$ thus

the antiderivative is: $$\frac{f}{g}$$

in this case it is enough simple to see!